# How would you do public key encryption by hand?

Tags: encryption, public-key-encryption, public-key

Can the public key encryption method be used if you were to encrypt and decrypt messages by hand using the pen and paper method? If so then how would you do it?

If it's possible, then can you provide a step-by-step example, perhaps by using keys that are only a few bits in length?

Comment: Computers are just *really really really fast* hands given large amounts of paper. There are numerous college courses (and related material that can be found online) that cover a wide range of cryptography detail and application. In practice, computer hands are too fast for a human to replicate - but the basic process can be manually followed and abstracted at smaller scales.

Comment: it's just math, so... yes, you can do it. would you want to? no. you'd never even get past generating the first prime if you did it all by hand.

Comment: [There are countless examples of doing RSA encryption by hand](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/search?q=rsa+by+hand), if that is what you want to do. But as Marc B puts it, if you want key sizes which provide real security, then it would take years to even get the first of ten steps done. Not all steps are equally hard though. The first two take a long time.

Comment: for "processing efficiency" symmetric is a lot easier...

Comment: There are two parts to public key encryption:  asymmetric key exchange and then a symmetric encryption.  You should look into the "discrete logarithm problem", which is how all of these work regardless of if it's RSA, ECC or anything else.  Winfield Diffie is the name of the author for the original work.